# Spring Boot external configuration using @PropertySource annotation with file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and I want to read properties from external file using place holder `@PropertySource("file:${application_properties}")`, so used annotation in configuration files as mentioned and defined
`@Bean`,

```
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

But I am getting:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'application_properties' in value "file:${application_properties}"

I configured applications_properties in `tomcat server.xml/context.xml` (not sure about which is file exactly)

Note: Its working fine if I use `@PropertySource("file:c:\filename")` but I want to use placeholder and want to define that place holder in tomcat (Want to know how to do that as well). Could you please help me to read the file properties using `@PropertySource` which will read the place holder defined in tomcat.

Thanks

Comment: One more update is I want to use file only not classpath

Comment: You cannot. At startup only the system and environment variables are taken into account when replacing placeholders. Also you don't need a bean for `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as Spring Boot already adds that one.

Comment: Can we add these variables in any tomcat file so that when we start tomcat it loads all these system and environment variables?(I know that we can pass as argument from eclipse but any possibility of adding those variables to file, so that we can keep track of all properties.

Answer (score 1):

The below class file has two properties files sql.properties & errorDefinition.properties files (/src/main/resource)

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:sql.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:errorDefinition.properties")
})
public class PropConfig {

    public PropConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Thirumal, but I am not sure how it is related to above question?

Comment: The best solution to your question is "spring-cloud-config-server".  This microservice will get properties from any path in your system as long as it in git. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below.

```
@PropertySource("file:${app.home}/app.properties")
```

and pass during startup like below.

```
System.setProperty("app.home", "test");

java -jar -Dapp.home="/home/mkyon/test" example.jar
```

see [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

Comment: Alien,Thanks for the answer.Is there any way we define that place holder property in tomcate and access in spring boot?

Comment: Why you wanna do that? keep all the files inside resources folder of your project and use by classpath..that is the easiest way.

Comment: Because I want to change the file location according to the environment and that change should be external to the application.

Comment: ok..then you can keep the file inside tomcat and can read using String tomcatPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
   File dir = new File(tomcatPath + File.separator + "propertiesFileFolder");

Comment: ok.What requirement is, suppose I have a some xml(context/server) file in tomcat where I will give like context param name and value as file location so that I will use that param name in spring boot configuration class as place holder.Any solution according to that